# How to connect Hive with Power BI

Tags: hive, powerbi

I cannot see Hive as a listed data source in power BI . Is there a way to connect Hive database with power bi desktop. also is there any limitation?

Answer (score 1):

Hive ODBC Driver should be installed and configured in the system in order to connect with Power BI. Once ODBC Driver is successfully configured then connect using below way in Power BI.

Home -> Get Data -> More -> Other -> ODBC

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here  [Create Hive ODBC data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver#create-hive-odbc-data-source)
The hive sample table Hive table comes with all HDInsight clusters.

Sign in to Power BI Desktop.
Click the Home tab, click Get Data from the External data, and then select More.

1. [connect data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Szw.png)
2. From the Get Data pane, click Other from the left, click ODBC from the right, and then click Connect on the bottom.
3. From the From ODBC pane, select the data source name you created in the last section, and then click OK.
4. From the Navigator pane, expand ODBC->HIVE->default, select hive sampletable, and then click Load.
   Thanks.