# Can we use JDBC connector to get data in Power BI

Tags: jdbc, odbc, powerbi

Usually we can get data using ODBC connector in Power BI. Is there any way to get the data using the JDBC connector?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no native support for JDBC.

You can upvote the feature request for JDBC [at this link](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7262643-support-jdbc-data-sources)

There are options that convert your JDBC connection in to an ODBC one, known as JDBC to ODBC bridges. [Oracle has one](https://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html) and [here is a Progress option](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/use-your-custom-jdbc-driver-with-microsoft-power-bi). Once configured you can then use the PowerBI ODBC connector.

Comment: Than you Murray for the inputs. Will be checking this to implement. We have to connect to HIVE using Power BI JDBC connector. Are there any JDBC-ODBC bridge for HIVE connectivity?

Comment: Yes, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377381/how-to-connect-hive-with-power-bi

Comment: Thanks Murray!! Working on this issue. Will see how it goes.